# A strange condition on containment of special complex numbers in cyclotomic fields

Tags: nt.number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, cyclotomic-fields

In a recent theorem we have naturally come across this condition, that seems to be important, but rarely satisfied: 
$\sqrt{\frac 1 4 + a^m} \in \mathbb Q(\zeta_m, a)$
where $a\in\mathbb C^*$ and $\zeta_m$ is a primitive $m$-th root of unity.

We are interested in an equivalent condition for any $a$, but we learned here that the condition for some $a$ seems to be just a technical obstacle of our method of proof and not intrinsic to the problem.

We are especially interested in the case where $a$ is a root of unity. We have checked that the containment condition is fulfilled, whenever $a^m=1$ and $5\mid m$ as this reduces to $\sqrt 5\in\mathbb Q(\zeta_m,a)$ or $a^m=-1$ and $3\mid m$ as this reduces to $\sqrt{-3}\in\mathbb Q(\zeta_m, a)$. Numerically these seem to be the only examples at $a$ root of unity and they all lead to different results in our theorem. So we believe that the condition is natural.

Is there a way to prove that these conditions are equivalent to the containment condition for $a$ root of unity - maybe using algebraic number theory?

Comment: You want this to be impossible for $a \in \mathbf{C}^*$ and $|a| < 1/4$, with no other conditions on $a$? Then you're out of luck. Let $\rho$ be a rational number a tiny little bit bigger than 1/2 (but smaller than $\sqrt{1/4 + 1/4^m}$). Then there's a unique real algebraic number $a \in (0, 1/4)$ such that $\sqrt{1/4 + a^m} = \rho$, and for this $a$ the condition that $\sqrt{1/4 + a^m} \in \mathbf{Q}(\zeta_m, a)$ is vacuously satisfied because $\rho \in \mathbf{Q}$.

Comment: (PS: I suspect this isn't an answer to the question you meant to ask, so can you refine the question to rule out such silliness?)

Answer (score -1):

Your characterization is correct. When $a$ is a root of unity, the question reduces to understanding when $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{1 + 4 \zeta})$ is an abelian extension (and $\zeta$ is a root of unity). This occurs only for $\zeta = +1$ or $-1$. As you suspect, one can prove this using [elementary] algebraic number theory. Writing the details on an iPhone is a bit annoying, so I will leave that to someone else.

Comment: Please flesh out this answer once you are off your iPhone and at a computer, when you get a chance.

Comment: What's a computer?

Comment: Whatever instrument you would use to post a proper MO answer. (I'm not playing games here.)